# Propagating Uncertainties through The Eigenvalue Problem

Tags: statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a physics lab we are studying a hanging coupled-spring oscillator with three masses, $M_i$, and three springs with spring constants $k_i$. From Newton's laws, ignoring the gravitational force, and assuming the springs are ideal, we derived the following 3-by-3 matrix to describe the system:
$$
\textbf{K}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{k_1+k_2}{M_1} & \frac{k_2}{M_1} & 0\\
\frac{k_2}{M_2} & -\frac{k_2+k_3}{M_2} & \frac{k_3}{M_2}\\
0 & \frac{k_3}{M_3} & -\frac{k_2+k_3}{M_3}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Since the eigenvalues represent the normal mode frequencies (once appropriately multiplying them by some constants) and the eigenvectors represent the relative offset positions for the normal modes, we are interested in finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors as well as the uncertainty of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors as each $k_i$ has some uncertainty (on a scale of $10^{-2}$).

Is there a method that will properly evaluate the uncertainties of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

A method we tried was to randomly select $10,000$ values from each $k_i$ $68\%$ confidence interval and average the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, however, this method failed due to both the large magnitude of the uncertainties and the sensitivity of the eigenvalue problem.

Comment: Also, all calculation are being completed in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ to avoid confusion.
The singular value decomposition of $\mathbf{X}$ writes
$$\mathbf{X}=\sum_k \sigma_k \mathbf{u}_k \mathbf{v}_k^T$$
The sensitivity of the first singular value writes
$$
\frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
= \mathbf{u}_1 \mathbf{v}_1^T
$$
and in particular
$
\frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial X_{11}}
= u_{11} v_{11}
$
Using chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial k_{1}}
=\frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial X_{11}}
\frac{\partial X_{11}}{\partial k_{1}}
=
-\frac{1}{M}_1 u_{11} v_{11}
$$
This gives you the sensitivity of the first singular value to change in $k_1$.
The other terms are derived in the same way. Maybe you can start to validate this before doing further computations.